# How to add help to eclipse help content?

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin

I have plugin of documentation for help in eclipse.

I have tool that base on eclipse.

How I can add this plugin that will be part of the eclipse content help ?

Comment: Try - Help > Install new Software

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This article describes in detail how to create a documentation plugin that contributes to the Eclipse help plugin: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/os-echelp/

PS: I'm not a fan of link-only answers but a) the article is too long to copy&paste here, b) it would probably be illegal/violate some copyright and c) unless I get an error message or specific problem, I don't know which part of the article would help.